# Laravel- multi layered relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm working on a quick project where i have multiple multi-layered relationship and I'm struggling with one in particular here's a quick description :
[image]
- a many-to-many relation between Users & Sports a typical : $user->sports

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function sports()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport');
    }
 }

class Sport extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

-now i want to add a Comment model where the user will input a quick  description on each sport so what kind of relation should i use in here to map each sport with it's own comment. one to many?

Comment: Does the `Comment` need to be a model? It could be a simple column on the `users_sports` table, then use `->withPivot(['comment'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the pivot table.

```
+-----+                              +------+
|users|                              |sports|
+-----+                              +------+
|id   |         +----------+         |id    |
|name |------->>|user_sport|<<-------|name  |
+-----+         +----------+         +------+
                |id        |
                |user_id   |
                |sport_id  |
                |comment   |
                +----------+
```

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function sports()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport')->withPivot('comment');
    }
}
```

```php
class Sport extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('comment');
    }
}
```

```php
# example of saving a comment
$user = User::find($user_id);

$user->sports()->attach($soccer_id, ['comment' => 'I really like soccer!']);
```

Comment: I agree with the pivot.  Please note you can still define a model for a pivot table should you ever require functionality there.

Comment: Yes, as described here in the docs. In my experience though, pivot tables don't need functionality. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: I agree there aren't many use cases, but sometimes there are ;-)  Just wanted to have the op know it is possible.  Your answer was perfectly fine :-)